# Shorten without using break

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
fun = input("Enter 1 or 2:")
if fun == '1':
   print("Programming is fun!")
elif fun == '2':
   print("You're getting the hang of this.")
elif fun == 'bye':
  print("Bye, bye.")
else:
    print("Sorry that isn't a 1 or 2.")
while fun != 'bye':
    fun = input("Enter 1 or 2:")
    if fun == '1':
        print("Programming is fun!")
    elif fun == '2':
        print("You're getting the hang of this.")
    elif fun == 'bye':
        print("Bye, bye.")
    else:
        print("Sorry that isn't a 1 or 2.")
```

So basically as the title says I was wondering if there was a way to shorten this without using the break statement?

Comment: and why do you not want to use `break`?

Comment: I'm currently a first year programming student so sorry if this is a stupid question?
Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean 'shorten'?

Comment: My teacher basically says using break is incorrect

Comment: get a new teacher then

Comment: lol a little too late to do that

Comment: Do you have a version that uses break that is shorter? You should show us that. As an aside, always use the generic [python] tag for any python related quesiton

Comment: And when I say shorten I wanted to try and not have to essentially repeat the code

Comment: @Blackasnight69 That's a bit disappointing to hear that about your teacher, because `break` is a very valid technique to escape loops early. Now, if you absolutely want to avoid it, you can put the loop in a function and use `return` instead.

Comment: Okay im doing this all wrong lol sorry guys

Comment: Add the code as an edit to your question

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this:

```
fun = ""
while fun != 'bye':
    fun = input("Enter 1 or 2:")
    if fun == '1':
        print("Programming is fun!")
    elif fun == '2':
        print("You're getting the hang of this.")
    elif fun == 'bye':
        print("Bye, bye.")
    else:
        print("Sorry that isn't a 1 or 2.")
```

Of course, with the new "walrus" operator in Python 3.8, you can use this:

```
while (fun := input("Enter 1 or 2:")) != 'bye':
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Using break is a perfectly valid programming technique can definitely be used to write neat and performant code that is easy to use. Saying that it is simply bad is a blanket statement that isn't true.  And you're right you can use it in this example as well.

However, you can still shorten the code and not use `break` by using a single `while` loop and put all your logic in there.  See below for example:

```
fun = ''
while fun != 'bye':
    fun = input("Enter 1 or 2:")
    if fun == '1':
        print("Programming is fun!")
    elif fun == '2':
        print("You're getting the hang of this.")
    elif fun == 'bye':
        print("Bye, bye.")
    else:
        print("Sorry that isn't a 1 or 2.")
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you can use dictionaries but they are great for cases like this:

```
fun = ""
choices = {'1': "Programming is fun!",
           '2': "You're getting the hang of this.",
           'bye': "Bye, bye."}
while fun != 'bye':
    fun = input("Enter 1 or 2:")
    print(choices.get(fun.lower(), "Sorry that isn't a 1 or 2.")
```

Using `dict.get` let's you supply a default value as the second argument which is essentially an else statement.

Answer (score 1):

The other replies answer your specific question and detail how to avoid both `return` and `break`, but since you might read other people's code, know that typically we would simply write:

```
while True: # <--- No check before entering the loop.
    fun = input("Enter 1 or 2:")
    if fun == '1':
       print("Programming is fun!")
    elif fun == '2':
       print("You're getting the hang of this.")
    elif fun == 'bye':
      print("Bye, bye.")
      break # Nice and explicit exit point. 
    else:
        print("Sorry that isn't a 1 or 2.")
```

If you were in a function, you could use  a `return` instead of a `break` there.

You might also want to broaded the range of accepted inputs. For example you want to support `"bye"` regardless of the case, by using `if fun.lower() == "bye":`. You can also support inputs like `" 1"` or "2  "`. In the end, that code would be more robust:

```
while True: # <--- No check before entering the loop.
    fun = input("Enter 1 or 2:")

    # If the input is a text, check if it's a variant of "bye".
    if fun.lower() == 'bye':
      print("Bye, bye.")
      break

    # Otherwise check if it's 1 or 2.
    else:
        # If the conversion to integer fails, print error message.
        try:
            fun = int(fun)
        except ValueError:
            print("Sorry that isn't a 1 or 2.")

        # If it works, handle as usual.
        if fun == 1:
            print("Programming is fun!")
        elif fun == 2:
            print("You're getting the hang of this.")
```

Comment: See this is how I originally wrote it but he wanted me to not use break

Comment: @Blackasnight69 I assume he wanted to forbid the use of break to have you research other solutions, which is ok, but just know that you had it right the first time :)

Answer (score 1):

Walrus version:

```
while (fun := input("Enter 1 or 2:")) != 'bye':
    if fun == '1':
        print("Programming is fun!")
    elif fun == '2':
        print("You're getting the hang of this.")
    else:
        print("Sorry that isn't a 1 or 2.")
print("Bye, bye.")
```

Another variation:

```
replies = {'1': "Programming is fun!",
           '2': "You're getting the hang of this."}
while (fun := input("Enter 1 or 2:")) != 'bye':
    print(replies.get(fun, "Sorry that isn't a 1 or 2."))
print("Bye, bye.")
```

Comment: Ah, lovely use of the new walrus operator! It's a great use example.